# Qt Quick Window/Frame with Inner Shadow flickers while resizing

Tags: linux, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

When I resize a Qt Quick `ApplicationWindow` that contains a `Frame` with an `InnerShadow`, I see flickering and visual artifacts. The same is not true when I either do not replace the default border or if I use a simple rectangle for the `Frame` object.

I tested this on my laptop that runs a 64-bit `Arch Linux`. It has an Nvidia GTX 1060 Max Q graphics card and an integrated Intel graphics card. I ran the code both with and without `bumblebee`.

Any way to work around or eliminate this flickering? It is pretty bad. My code and some screen-grabs are as below

EDIT: I have tried setting `AA_ShareOpenGLContexts` and `AA_UseOpenGLES` (and its software/desktop variants) attributes with no luck.

UPDATE: I have created an issue here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81519, but I am still hoping someone can devise a workaround.

**test.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.14

ApplicationWindow{
    id: main
    width: 2*screen.width/3
    height: 2*screen.height/3
    title: "Test ApplicationWindow"  
    color: activeColorPalette.window 
    visible:true
    SystemPalette {
        id: activeColorPalette
        colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active
    }    
    Frame{
        anchors.fill: parent 
        anchors.margins: 10
        background: Item{
            id: root
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle{
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 1
                radius: 16
                color: activeColorPalette.window
            }
            InnerShadow {
                anchors.fill: root
                horizontalOffset: 0
                verticalOffset: 0
                source: root
                radius: 16
                color: activeColorPalette.shadow
                spread: 0.6        
                samples: 32        
                cached: true
                fast:true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Window without flickering or artifacts**

[image]

**Window with flickering/visual artifacts while resizing**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to eliminate the visual artifacts during resizing.

In my problem code, the `InnerShadow` used an `Item` QML type as the source, which is transparent by default and contained a grey `Rectangle` that I added within it. The visual distinction between the transparent source `Item` and the smaller child `Rectangle` inside it is what the `InnerShadow` uses to compute the shadow gradient within. The end result was a decorative shadow border. However, resizing the application resulted in ugly visual artifacts that would sometimes stay. Note: Changing the outer `Item` into a transparent `Rectangle` had no discernible effect.

But when I encapsulated the grey innermost rectangle into another transparent component like

> `Item` {transparent `Rectangle` {grey inner `Rectangle`} }

or like

> `Rectangle`{transparent `Rectangle`{grey inner `Rectangle`}}

**in addition to** setting the **middle** transparent `Rectangle` as the **source** for the `InnerShadow`, the visual artifacts are eliminated. Below is the working code for **test_workaround.qml** that you can compare to the `test.qml` above.

**test_workaround.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.14

ApplicationWindow{
    id: main
    width: 2*screen.width/3
    height: 2*screen.height/3
    title: "Test ApplicationWindow"  
    color: activeColorPalette.window 
    visible:true
    SystemPalette {
        id: activeColorPalette
        colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active
    }    
    Frame{
        anchors.fill: parent 
        anchors.margins: 10
        background: Item{
            id: root
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle{
                 id: middleRect
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 color: "transparent"           
                Rectangle{
                    id: innerRect
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 1
                    radius: 16
                    color: activeColorPalette.window
                }
            }
            InnerShadow {
                anchors.fill: root
                horizontalOffset: 0
                verticalOffset: 0
                source: middleRect
                radius: 16
                color: activeColorPalette.shadow
                spread: 0.6        
                samples: 32        
                cached: true
                fast:true
                smooth:true
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```